# Can a JavaFX Standalone JAR get a javascript reference to the Main java class?

Tags: java, javascript, jar, javafx

I apologize beforehand for anyone that dares shuffle through this code. I also thank you ahead of time!

I'm trying to launch a simple JavaFX standalone JAR and access my Java class from the javascript in order to call Java functions from the javascript.

I am using

```
document.getElementById("myApp");
```

but consistently getting null returned;

Here is the relevant code. I hope I didn't omit anything crucial.

## Build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="JavaFX Hello World" default="do-deploy" basedir="." xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
<target name="init-fx-tasks">
    <path id="fxant">
        <filelist>
            <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
            <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
        </filelist>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"      
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
        classpathref="fxant"/>
</target>
<target name="setup-staging-area">
    <delete dir="externalLibs" />
    <delete dir="project" />
    <delete dir="projectRefs" />
    
    <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />
    
    <mkdir dir="project" />
    <copy todir="project">
        <fileset dir="C:\Development\workspace\JavaFX Hello World">
            <include name="src/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    
    <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />
</target>
<target name='do-compile'>
    <delete dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="build/src" />
    <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

    <!-- Copy project-libs references -->
    <copy todir="build/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Copy project references -->

    <!-- Copy project sources itself -->
    <copy todir="build/src">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <javac includeantruntime="false" source="1.7" target="1.7" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="Cp1252">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="build/libs">
                <include name="*"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
    
    <!-- Copy over none Java-Files -->
    <copy todir="build/classes">
    <fileset dir="project/src">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">
    <delete file="dist"/>
    <delete file="dist/libs"/>
    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />
    
    <copy todir="dist/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />
    
    <fx:deploy placeholderid="myApp" id="myApp"
        width="640" height="480"
        outdir="web-dist" outfile="Fish">
        <fx:application id="myApp"
            mainClass="application.ModuleSimMain">
        </fx:application>
        <fx:resources id="appRes">
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="Module Simulator Gui.jar"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
        </fx:resources>
    </fx:deploy>
    
    <fx:jar destfile="dist/Module Simulator Gui.jar">
        <fx:application id="myApp"
                mainClass="application.ModuleSimMain">
        </fx:application>
        
        <fx:resources id="appRes">
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="Module Simulator Gui.jar"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
        </fx:resources> 
                
        <fileset dir="build/classes"/>
        
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value=""/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value=""/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value=""/>
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
        </manifest>
    </fx:jar>
</target>
</project>
```

Here's my main class;

## application.ModuleSimMain.java

```
public class ModuleSimMain extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        WebView browser = new WebView(); 
        final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
        final URL mainUrl = getClass().getResource("/content/ModuleSimulatorGui.html");
        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webEngine.load(mainUrl.toExternalForm());
        Scene scene = new Scene(browser);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Module Simulator - Protocol 2");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
                .addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                        if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            System.out.println("succeeded");
                            webEngine.executeScript("ModuleSimulatorGui.init();");
                        }
                    }
                });
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public String getText() {
    return "success!";
}
```

}

## content.ModuleSimulatorGui.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ModuleSimulatorGui.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ModuleSimulatorGui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    aofirwmnbrb<br/>
    aofirwmnbrb<br/>
    aofirwmnbrb<br/>
    aofirwmnbrb<br/>
    aofirwmnbrb<br/>
    aofirwmnbrb<br/>
    aofirwmnbrb<br/>
    aofirwmnbrb<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm omitting the CSS file because it only changes a background color and works.
So lastly is my javascript.

## content.ModuleSimulatorGui.js

```
var ModuleSimulatorGui = {
    init: function() {
        var fxapp = document.getElementById("myApp");
        if( fxapp == null ) {
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = 'null';
        } else {
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = fxapp.getText();
        }
    }
};
```

Anytime I build and run it, or run it from Eclipse I get a screen of the correct size and color (from my CSS file) with the word "null".

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround.
Ignore the build.xml based instructions.

https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx

I added a reference to my application in my main file

```
final ModuleSimMain moduleSimMain = this;
```

Then in the listener that runs once the app is started I inject a reference to it into the javascript.

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
                @Override
                public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                        jsobj.setMember("myApp", moduleSimMain);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

After doing that my javascript can call

```
myApp.myFunction();
```

successfully!

If anyone else experiences this problem and didn't follow what I did just ping me.